# Oracle MAF Data Control Issue while creating master detail relationship

Tags: jdeveloper, oracle-maf

I am developing an application using Oracle MAF and it's a master-detail based application. I am facing issues while consuming REST(JSON) based services.
The entire application is running successfully but when I am inserting detail information or consume REST-POST method it does not work accordingly.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[![enter image description here][9]][9]

[image: Master Detail Application]

[image: REST-POST Service not working]

Comment: What does *"it do not works accordingly"* mean? Please describe what happens - or does not happen - including any error messages. Remember we cannot see your screen or run your code, so all we know is what you tell us.

Comment: Thanks for your reply , actually i am using REST/JSON services and build master detail application.When we add information on master form it works fine but when we add information at detail level it does not reflect any changes

Comment: I have attached images of each steps, only issue is REST-POST service not working in master detail relation but when i develop single page application its working.

Comment: To be honest, MAF is a niche product, albeit seemingly a neat one which should be more popular. Not many questions on the topic get answered on this site. I think you've got a better chance of help if you post on [the official Oracle MAF forum](https://community.oracle.com/community/oracle-mobile/oraclemaf).